# ArcGIS: segmenting buffer based on polygon corners

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, buffer, polygon-creation

I have hundreds of square polygons which I've created a single continuous buffer around the polygons. What I'd like to try and do is try and break this buffer down into segments based on the corners of each polygon so that each polygon has 1 corresponding buffer  zone per side. Is there any way to do this? 
I've tried breaking the polygons down into polylines, and then attempted to extend the lines so I could cut the buffer up with those lines, but the extend line tool won't extend the lines the way I imagine.

I'm running ArcGIS 10.2.2, with the Advanced License.

Comment: so you want a buffer of each corner of each polygon square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure weather you want to base the buffer off of each line or each corner.

[Here](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00170000003t000000) is the Polygon to Line tool that may be of use to you in this scenario.  The result will give you some attributes of Left_FID and Right_FID which may be helpful if you are trying to classify each side.

If you want to base a buffer off of the corners, you can use [THIS](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Feature_Vertices_To_Points/00170000003p000000/) Feature Verticies to Points tool.  If you select "All" then you will get a point for each corner of each polygon.  Then you can run the buffer on these points.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I had used the Polygon to Line tool, and then my idea was to extend each one of the new lines, but I couldn't locate a tool in ArcGIS which would accomplish this for me. I've ended up thinking of a work around using FME to extend my the lines the way I wanted to.